# Migrating from jQuery to Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm starting to write code using Prototype coming from a jQuery background.  Is there any chart that shows the prototype equivalent method to use in place of specific jQuery methods?

More specifically, I'm looking for a $('#my-id').prepend('some stuff') equivalent in prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other folks here will know much more about prototypejs than I, but here's a prototypejs/javascript hybrid. Who knows, maybe this is how its done.

```
var $elem = $('my-id');

var newNode = document.createTextNode('some text')

$elem.insertBefore(newNode, $elem.firstChild);
```

Something tells me that prototypejs must have some easier way of creating text nodes, and/or prepending them.

---

**EDIT:**

I think I figured it out:

```
var $elem = $('my-id');  // Get element with ID 'my-id'

$elem.insert({top:'someText'} );  // insert 'someText' at top position in $elem
```

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert